# "What is your name" vs. "What your name is" in this context

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, punctuation

Which sentence is grammatical:

1. **Tell me, what is your name?**
2. **Tell me, what your name is.**

Tell me the uses of both the sentences along with correct punctuation marks.

Comment: Please avoid titles such as "Which is grammatically correct?" (Too many people do that, and the result is a messy heap of questions. [Have a look](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=Which+is+grammatically+correct).)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the comma in the second example, they're both completely fine.

The first is a question, with an imperative without an object as a fairly conventional addition. The second is a full imperative sentence - you are demanding they tell you something, rather than asking a question. Practically speaking, the meaning is very similar, but the nuance and emotional element is very different - as is the grammatical structure.

But lose the comma in the second example, it shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

In the first sentence, it just likes a normal question.

In second sentence it's `Noun clause` In English.
There are clauses that stand in the place of a noun. That is the noun clause. The noun clause is a clause that can act as a noun in the sentence. The sentence containing the noun clause is often a complex sentence. In the sentence, what noun does the task, the noun clause does that task.